# Multi sums into one box

Tags: excel

I'm  trying to work out how to subtract one figure from another then work out a percentage with that figure from another figure.

What I'm trying to do it work out the following in excel (using the cells and the ?*- bits).

Anyway here is the hard data:
12-5=7 then I need to do 5/(divided by) 7 (which is the answer from the first sum)x100 so this gives me a percentage (71.43%)

I have a write excel sheet which has all this data in (well sort of as some of the figures are results etc)

Comment: to be completely honest, it sounds like you need an excel tutorial, rather than just having a question answered. I would recommend doing some googling about "excel formula tutorial" and see where that takes you. Good luck. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let's presume you have those numbers as variables in cells. So for example :
A1 = 12
A2 = 5
A3 = A2/(A1-A2) * 100